# How do I configure my Linux computer to provide Internet to a FreeBSD computer via Ethernet port?

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd, ethernet

I have FreeBSD computer to which I want to provide with an Internet connection via the Ethernet port.

I bought a single board computer (SBC Wangboard DUAL) onto which I have installed Ubuntu.

I have configured the SBC to connect to my wireless network. So far so good.

Now I want to use this Linux machine to provide Internet to another computer (FreeBSD) via a WIRED Ethernet connection (No wireless)

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

wifi-router W --------> internet server A ---------> internet client B

(A) internet providing linux: enable ip forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

(B1) internet client computer: easy way

- if B is configured as DHCP client, and wifi router's dhcp works well,
  then no further tasks needed, everything should work

(B2) internet client computer: manual settings

- set IP addres to something that belong to wirelless network subnet (mask)
- set default gateway to ip address of wifi-server (W)
- add preferred dns server

B comp can be linux, unix, windows ... not sure what are freeBSD alternatives/variations are but linux commands for B2 tasks would be something like this:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.33              ... (ipAddrB outside wifi-server-dhcp-ip-range)
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1  ... (if srv W is on ip ..22 for example)
echo 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf      ... (or better edit manually with text-editor)
```

Comment: I tried your B1 alternative, but I can't access the internet from B1. Looks like I need some forwarding rules using `iptables` (?) at least that's what I have been reading.

Comment: @joelmaranhao hm... strange because i used iptables for udp and specific range forwarding and proxy(masquarade)... but for simple forwarding above (A) line was for sure enough on debian, ubuntu and arch... can you ping A from B? if not than dhcp is not ok

Comment: yes the ping works. and so does the SSH from client to server. I will try harder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you are doing it over wireless then do not even try to bridge it. Because that was how the question sounded like. Wlan has this strange problem that it can not be bridged in client wifi mode. Thats because it can not transmit a different MAC address. There is only one per client. There are dirty hacks, like MAC address translation (something like NAT for IPv4) sometimes used in wifi range extenders, but this is not reliable at all.
The only way how to do it is either you configure that ubuntu like a router, or you just get a wifi adapter that is supported under FreeBSD and connect the FreeBSD machine to the wifi as just another wifi client. Keep it simple!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure Ubuntu as a router](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router).